# I want to scrape Data from HTML and convert it into pandas DataDrame finally store it as aCSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys,csv,os
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html



#url = r'https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=137&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-jan-2016&DateTo=19-nov-2019&Fr_Date=01-jan-2016&To_Date=19-nov-2019&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Ajwan&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--'


Export_Path = r"E:\Knoema_Work_Dataset"

Res = requests.get(url)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Res.content,'lxml')
#print(Soup.prettify())


mylists = ['137','281','325','166','86','130']
for mylist in mylists:
    url = 'https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity='+mylist+'+&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-jan-2016&DateTo=19-nov-2019&Fr_Date=01-jan-2016&To_Date=19-nov-2019&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Ajwan&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--'+ mylist
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class':'tableagmark_new'})
    DataAll = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['State Name','District Name','Market Name','Variety','Group','Arrivals (Tonnes)','Min Price (Rs./Quintal)','Max Price (Rs./Quintal)','Modal Price (Rs./Quintal)','Reported Date'],dtype = object,index=range(0,1000))
    row_marker = 0
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        column_marker = 0
        columns = row.findAll('td')
        for column in columns:
            DataAll.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
            column_marker += 1

    DataAll

Export_Path_F = os.path.join(Export_Path, 'aggr.csv')
DataAll.to_csv(Export_Path_F, encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

I am getting only the last row in a table in the dataframe 'DataAll'
i need full table to be plotted on the Dataframe
I made iterations to scrape data from multiple table to a single dataframe 
please help me so that i can get all the contents in dataframe

Url = https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=137&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-jan-2016&DateTo=19-nov-2019&Fr_Date=01-jan-2016&To_Date=19-nov-2019&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Ajwan&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--

Comment: You didn't increment the variable `row_marker `.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: instead of using `column_marker = 0` and `column_marker += 1` you can use `enumerate()` - `for column_marker, column in enumerate(columns)`. Similar for `row_marker`

Comment: you coulc create list with all item in row or with all rows and then append row - `DataAll.append( [  [...], [...], [...] ] )`